# C# redirect input console application not working

Tags: c#, redirect, subprocess, console-output

I have an interesting situation. I am trying to run a program from the command line and I cannot programatically redirect its input for some reason. The executable I am running is called. **Spideroakone.exe**. This executable asks for a password. When I type the password lets say the password is "asd" I can actually see what I am typing in plain text. I get an error message:

```
'asd' is not recognized as an internal or external command ...
```

If I run the executable like that :

```
cmd /c Spideroakone.exe
```

then again I see the same I am asked for a password. Then I type asd. But I can't see what I am typing and the password works and there is no error.

Now what I want to do is write an app that will execute **Spideroak.exe** and pass the password on the standard input. However because of the weird behaviour of Spideroak I am unable to pass any standard input to it nor I am able to read the standard output. When try to do that my app blocks on the writeline command. I would have expected to see the word "Password:" in the stdout. I have tried some async examples and multithreading but non of that works. The standard output buffer is always empty. I wonder what is this text I am seeing "Password:" if it is not written to the stdout where it is written?

this is the code I use. Which blocks on the `ReadToEnd()` line. This exact code works fine with a console app that I made so this makes me think the executable I am trying to execute is written in a weird way, but in a command line window it works fine:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c ""C:\Program Files\SpiderOakONE\SpiderOakONE.exe"" --headless";
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

myProcess.Start();

string s = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

This is the screenshot of the exact debug window and the line it blocks on:

[image]

This is what I see in the command line window:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add some code to provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does anyone also by the way know how to redirect the output of the currently open cmd to a file. I mean when I type 
asdf 
on the command prompt I will see a message 
'...is not recognized as an internal or external command...'
I want to see this message in a file. How does one do that? it might be related to my problem.

Comment: No its not that. This was because error output is different than standard output.

Comment: I also tried Console.Writeline("test"); 
This actually prints the text on the console but it doesn't get passed to the spideroakone.exe so it just shows up as plain text and the exe doesn't react.

Answer (score 1):

Well no one responded and in the mean time I found the answer. I did not find the exact reason why stdout and stdin are not working but I read an article that someone else was complaining that old programs written in C using getch() will behave that way. I wanted to do it in a more pretty way but this is what I came up with. Basically sending key strokes to the console window. I wasn't sure if this will work because I am starting the process in Task Scheduler and there is no visual window created but it seems working fine.

I start the process in a separate thread:

```
new Thread(() =>
        {
        Process myProcess = new Process();

        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c ""C:\Program Files\SpiderOakONE\SpiderOakONE.exe"" --headless";
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.Start();

        myProcess.WaitForExit();
        }).Start();
```

Then I enumerate all windows:

```
EnumWindows(EnumTheWindows, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Then I look for the window of my process and send the desired key strokes to it. The Sleep in between is required without it is not working. The sample password I am sending is 'asd'

```
private static bool EnumTheWindows(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        uint pidCurWindow;
        uint CurWindowThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out pidCurWindow);
        int CurrentPID = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

        if (pidCurWindow == CurrentPID)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VkKeyScan('a'), 0);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VkKeyScan('s'), 0);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VkKeyScan('d'), 0);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 1);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I hope this will help someone save time.

Comment: I'm having the same issue now.. could you please share a working example?

Comment: Sorry I no longer keep that code. It was too long ago.